# Debug .NET app with IIS7 and Delphi.NET - Use aspnet_regiis.exe to configure the local IIS web server

Tags: asp.net, delphi, iis-7, delphi-7, delphi.net

I have been trying to set up local debugging for my ASP.NET app in Delphi and am getting the error above. I have used the aspnet_regiis.exe tool with the following:

```
Aspnet_regiis.exe -s W3SVC/1/ROOT/DevTest
```

but this hasn't helped. It added it to IIS as an application but I am still getting the error:

```
The project cannot be debugged because virtual directory "DevTes" is not configured with ASP.NET version 2.0 or 3.0  Use aspnet_regiis.exe to configure the local IIS web server.
```

I am not really sure where to go from here so need some help please:

Machine specs: Windows 7 64bit, IIS7, Using RAD Studio 2007.

EDIT: For more info, I have been able to start the website in Firefox and have been able to attach to process now, although the debugging is lacking a little, i.e I can't see values of sessions ect ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Web Platform Installer to configure IIS for ASP.NET development.  http://www.microsoft.com/web/Downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: I have downloaded and installed this but cannot really see how it can help. I have most of the things installed it has listed.